# handleMessage Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android, multithreading

I can't reproduce this problem, but I got some bug reports

**Exception** android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

sample

```
 SampleActivity extends Activity{
   private Messenger callBackMessenger = new Messenger(new CallBackHandler(this));
 }

  private static class CallBackHandler extends Handler {
    public CallBackHandler(SampleActivity activity) {
          context = new WeakReference<>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      TestActivity a = context.get();
      if(a!=null){
      a.textView.setText("text"); <<crash 
    }
}
```

bind and unBind call from onStart and onStop

handleMessage should processed in UI(if created in UI). I want to correct the cause of the wrong behavior. runOnUiThread is workaround.

Comment: post your relevant code. Need more info to know whats wrong

Comment: @Raghunandan I don't understand why handleMessage(handler created in UI-Th) processed in non-UI thread. Sorry, I can't put all code.

Comment: looking at the code does not give us a hint of what runs on the ui thread or background thread. Sorry i can't help further

Answer (score 0):

Put a.uodateUI in runOnUiThread

public CallBackHandler(TestActivity activity) {
              context = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

```
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 

      TestActivity a = context.get();
      if(a!=null){
      a.runOnUiThread(new Runnable () {
      public void run() {
      a.updateUI(); <<crash
     } 
    }) ; 
    }
}
```

Comment: no wanna. handleMessage should processed in UI. I want to correct the cause of the wrong behavior. runOnUiThread is workaround.

Comment: No, it's running in background and can't update Ui in background.

Comment: it's running in background but should in UI